# Ao concatenar no LINQ me retorna erro

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Fiz essa LINQ. Na concatenação entre DDD e numero do telefone, o qual eu chamo de telefone1 está dando pau.

```cs
var agendamento = (
    from pdv in db.T_PDV
    from tarefa in db.T_TarefaParceiro.Where(trf => trf.CNPJ == pdv.CNPJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from parceiro in db.T_OsParceiro.Where(prf => prf.IDTarefaParceiro == tarefa.IDTarefaParceiro)
    from acao in db.T_Acao.Where(ac => ac.IDAcao == tarefa.IDAcao).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from proxima in db.T_ProximaAcao.Where(pxm => pxm.IDAcao == acao.IDAcao).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from info in db.T_InfoClientePdv.Where(inf => inf.CNPJ == pdv.CNPJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from cliente in db.T_Cliente.Where(clie => clie.IDCliente == info.IDCliente).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from usuariopdv in db.T_UsuarioPDV.Where(usu => usu.IDPDV == pdv.IDPdv)
    from usuario in db.T_Usuario.Where(us => us.IDUsuario == usuariopdv.IDUsuario)

    where pdv.CNPJ == _agendamento.Cnpj //&& parceiro.NumOs == _agendamento.Os

    orderby parceiro.DataVisita descending

    select new
    {
     pdv.CNPJ,
     pdv.DataCadastro,
     cliente.RazaoSocial,
     acao.Acao,
     proxima.ProximaAcao,
     parceiro.IDOsParceiro,
     parceiro.NumOs,
     parceiro.DataVisita,
     parceiro.DataAgendamento,
     parceiro.Tecnico,
     usuario.Nome,
     telefone1 = "(" + usuario.DDD + ")" + usuario.Telefone
    })
    .ToList()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

O ***erro*** que está dando é o seguinte:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: pnet qual os tipos do DDD e Telefone?

Comment: int e string, acho que é isso, certo? Mas numa concatenação ele não faz o cast automático?

Comment: Sim, os nomes dos tipos são `int` e `string`. Sim, o cast dos tipos primitivos para string é automático. Não é necessário o `.ToString()` nesse caso. Veja a correção que fiz na minha resposta. Deve te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Coloque assim:***

```
var agendamento = (
    from pdv in db.T_PDV
    from tarefa in db.T_TarefaParceiro.Where(trf => trf.CNPJ == pdv.CNPJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from parceiro in db.T_OsParceiro.Where(prf => prf.IDTarefaParceiro == tarefa.IDTarefaParceiro)
    from acao in db.T_Acao.Where(ac => ac.IDAcao == tarefa.IDAcao).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from proxima in db.T_ProximaAcao.Where(pxm => pxm.IDAcao == acao.IDAcao).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from info in db.T_InfoClientePdv.Where(inf => inf.CNPJ == pdv.CNPJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from cliente in db.T_Cliente.Where(clie => clie.IDCliente == info.IDCliente).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from usuariopdv in db.T_UsuarioPDV.Where(usu => usu.IDPDV == pdv.IDPdv)
    from usuario in db.T_Usuario.Where(us => us.IDUsuario == usuariopdv.IDUsuario)

    where pdv.CNPJ == _agendamento.Cnpj //&& parceiro.NumOs == _agendamento.Os

    orderby parceiro.DataVisita descending

    select new
    {
     pdv.CNPJ,
     pdv.DataCadastro,
     cliente.RazaoSocial,
     acao.Acao,
     proxima.ProximaAcao,
     parceiro.IDOsParceiro,
     parceiro.NumOs,
     parceiro.DataVisita,
     parceiro.DataAgendamento,
     parceiro.Tecnico,
     usuario.Nome,
     telefone1 = "(" + usuario.DDD ?? "00" + ")" + usuario.Telefone
    })    
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

***Obs:*** *Não precisa dar um [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) e depois um [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), já coloque o [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que vai resolver o problema, além de ser desnecessário o [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) vai trazer tudo da sua tabela e o [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pega a primeira ocorrência na memória, isso acarreta performace.*

Comment: Ele diz que não reconhece o ToString() no LinqToEntities

Comment: Acho que eu vou concatenar no jquery e resolve esse problema. Sempre que eu tento concatenar ou renomear um campo como eu tentei fazer, dá pau

Comment: Eu sei, foi o que eu fiz e continua dando erro. Concatenando no jquery é mais fácil. Sempre q tento no LINQ dá erro, sempre. Nunca consegui fazer, renomear campos como eu fiz, criar um Alias

Comment: Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que o seu problema seja com o a variável `usuario`

Mude:

```
telefone1 = "(" + usuario.DDD + ")" + usuario.Telefone
```

Para:

```
telefone1 = usuario == null ? "não informado" : "(" + usuario.DDD + ")" + usuario.Telefone
```